timeseries model choose LSTM VS ARIMA
if have i have a academic data like their grade for each subject (multivariate) for 5 semester and i want to classify if the student will pursue STEM OR NON STEM. is it better to use LSTM or ARIMA approach. or is it not a timeseries approach?

ARIMA forecasts numerical values. You could use it to forecast the student's future grades separately (and it would likely not work very well), but it will not help you in classifying a student as to their future field of study.
LSTM is also a forecasting tool. It might be adaptable to be a classification tool... but the adaptations would pretty much turn it into something that is not LSTM any more.
I personally would not see this situation as very much of a time series problem, rather one of classification with features that are themselves temporally dependent. Given enough data, a classification tool might figure out how to deal with the temporal dynamics in the features. Or you might need to include this in your feature engineering yourself, e.g., by exponentially smoothing the grades in a particular subject and only using the smoothed end result as a feature for your classifier.
